# Iterate in a forEach loop, Stream<Path>

Tags: foreach, stream

This code will print all directories below the root directory `destDir`
But I want to get the directory names in a String variable, or a linked list while doing ForEach

Not quite used to use this forEach clause, so what should I do in the forEach loop to get the names of the directories? Replace `System.out::println` with some nice code?

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(destDir))) {
    paths.filter(Files::isDirectory).forEach(System.out::println); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use File.list method and assing to array:

```
String[] pathnames = new File("destDirPath").list();
```

This finds all files and directories. If you want to find only directory, you can use filter like that:

```
FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f, String name) {
        return f.isDirectory();
    }
};
```

Use filter as argument:

```
File[] onlyDirs = new File("destDirPath").listFiles(filter);
```

You can get directory names with `getName()` method.

Comment: I have tried something like this, but it does not give me all subfolders below root directory. Only gives first level of subdirectories. The method I asked about gives all subfolders. Or am I missing something? Anyway, looking for a code to loop in the list that is hidden inside the 'forEach"

Comment: You can write recursively method to list all inner folder and files. Call again same method if it is directory.